# How can i check that droppable element has already an element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have implement draggable and droppable element. one is draggable and other two are droppable.
now i want to check that droppable element has contains already an element.

now i want to drop one elements in each block and after that give notification that all droppable element has one element.

please refer this `fiddle` - http://jsfiddle.net/Sanjayrathod/aNreg/113/

Comment: Please read: [Prevent posts with links to jsfiddle and no code](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149890/prevent-posts-with-links-to-jsfiddle-and-no-code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

Script:

```
 var isAllFilled = true;
    $(".shoppingCart").each(function(){
        if($(this).find('ol .placeholder').length > 0)
        {
            isAllFilled = false;
            return
        }
               });
    if(isAllFilled)
    {
        alert('All Boxes have elements.');
    }
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/abhishekjain/aNreg/114/)

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/abhishekjain/aNreg/115/)

Comment: I actually i mean if each block has elements than it should be displays that all blocks have elements now.

Comment: Check the updated fiddle, i think this is what you have asked for.